# Viable way to check variable to input JS

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input, captcha

I am trying to create a custom CAPTCHA for a project and i was wondering how i could check to see if an input was equal to a variable.

```
window.onload = function makeid() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var place = document.getElementById("random");
    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    };
        console.log(text);
        place.innerHTML = text;
        };
    };
```

BTW i am new to javascript.

The random string generator portion is not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a captcha in a span, all that is left to do is placing an input box, retrieving its contents and comparing them to the captcha.(I used Ali 's code as a starting point)

```js
        window.onload = function makeid() {
            var text = "";
            var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            var place = document.getElementById("random");

            for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
            };

            console.log(text);
            place.innerHTML = text;
        };

        //This code waits for the user to press the enter key in order to trigger the function that compares the strings
        inputbox = document.getElementById("userinput"); inputbox.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) { //checks whether the pressed key is "Enter"
                validate(e);
            }
        });

        //And this actually performs the comparison and shows a response
        function validate(e) {
            var captchatext = document.getElementById("random").innerHTML;
            var usertext = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
            if (captchatext == usertext) {
                alert("Correct captcha");
            } else {
                alert("Incorrect captcha");
            }
        }
```

```html
        <span id = "random" > < /span>
<input id = "userinput" type = "text" >
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was after. Is it possible to change from pressing [Enter] to press a button?

Comment: Yes of course, different keys have different keycodes, the one for [Enter] just happens to be 13, which is why the line `if (e.keyCode === 13) {` checks if it's 13, see point 3.3 of [this page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) or, [this interactive one](http://keycode.info/) for reference.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, i was asking about replacing the keyCode with a physical button the user has to click  with their mouse. But i managed to fix the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix some syntax issues:

```js
window.onload = function makeid() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var place = document.getElementById("random");
    
    for( var i=1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    };
    
    console.log(text);
    place.innerHTML = text;
 };
```

```html
<span id="random"></span>
```

If you want to increase a length of your generated string, just replace this condition `i <= 5` with the other, for example: `i <= 15` -> 15 symbols